# SendMail 503 error Ubuntu ["Unrecognized host name gmail.com."]

Tags: mail, smtp, sendmail

```
Unrecognized host name gmail.com.
503 5.0.0 Need RCPT (recipient)
```

This error if i send mail in any email *@gmail.com

How do I enable sending mail to all addresses?

```
news@ovz1:~$ nslookup gmail.com
Server:         10.100.10.2
Address:        10.100.10.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   gmail.com
Address: 173.194.32.182
Name:   gmail.com
Address: 173.194.32.181

root@ovz1:~# echo 3,0 x@gmail.com | sendmail -d8.20 -bt
_res.options = 812c3, HasWildcardMX = 0
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> canonify           input: x @ gmail . com
Canonify2          input: x < @ gmail . com >
dns_getcanonname(gmail.com, trymx=1)
dns_getcanonname: trying gmail.com. (AAAA)
        YES
dns_getcanonname: gmail.com
Canonify2        returns: x < @ gmail . com . >
canonify         returns: x < @ gmail . com . >
parse              input: x < @ gmail . com . >
Parse0             input: x < @ gmail . com . >
Parse0           returns: x < @ gmail . com . >
Parse1             input: x < @ gmail . com . >
MailerToTriple     input: < > x < @ gmail . com . >
MailerToTriple   returns: x < @ gmail . com . >
Parse1           returns: $# error $@ 5 . 1 . 2 $: "553 Unrecognized host name " gmail . com .
parse            returns: $# error $@ 5 . 1 . 2 $: "553 Unrecognized host name " gmail . com .
```

Comment: what is the result of nslookup gmail.com

Comment: @RomeoNinov add to question

Comment: Please also check why you have this dot `.` at the end of address on the first line

Comment: @RomeoNinov dot is a punctuation in error, in the address it is not

Comment: Check also the content of  `nsswitch.conf` , line stating with `hosts`

Comment: As root execute the following test command: `echo 3,0 x@gmail.com | sendmail -d8.20 -bt`.  It should trace email address processing with DNS lookups.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip add result to quest

Comment: @RomeoNinov `hosts: files dns`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## sendmail: missing smtp mailer in `sendmail.mc`

It seems that `MAILER(smtp)` is missing in your `sendmail.mc` file.
Sendmail would like to use smtp to send to gmail.com but the mailer is missing.
[`sendmail.mc` is used to generate `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf`]

The missing line in `sendmail.mc`:

```
MAILER(`smtp')
```

---

### Technical details overkill

`proto.m4` file:

```
# deal with other remote names
ifdef(`_MAILER_smtp_',
`R$* < @$* > $*         $#_SMTP_ $@ $2 $: $1 < @ $2 > $3        user@host.domain',
`R$* < @$* > $*         $#error $@ 5.1.2 $: "_CODE553 Unrecognized host name " $2')
```